# The Blue USB's are the 3.0's, am I right?

Tags: usb3

I have to be sure, in order to connect my SDD properly: There are 4 USB-A connectors in pairs of 2 on my RPi4. The blue ones are 3.0 and the black ones 2.0?

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: yes, blue is 3.x, black is 2.x.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to be affirmed in my thoughts.

Comment: I have seen in the specs [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/) though that it are 'just' USB 3.0 ports. How can one distinguish them from each other afterwards? Is there a way to find out what's on my Pi from the command line?

Comment: that is a different, unrelated question ... this site is not a forum, please post a new question

Answer (score 4):

The answer was yes (as said in the comments). For completeness, the more or less standard colors are

- White: USB 1
- Black: USB 2
- Blue: USB 3

I understood, that the Pi sometimes used white adapters for USB 2 though.